# Access: Select multiple records from one table to add data in another

Tags: ms-access

I'm building a database to track student and parent activities in a few schools. Currently I have separate tables that contain school, teacher, student & family (I understand it isn't ideal to hold both student and parent info in one place, but it's what I have at the moment) and a form to collect the participation data.

School and teachers are linked. The student & family (S&F) table is linked to teacher and school. Participation data is liked to Student & Family through a unique student ID (primary key for S&F table).

I need to enter participation data linked to the student & family record. So far, I have a form based on the school with a subform for S&F and a second subform for the Participation Data. A listbox in the main form allows me to select a school, which then filters the S&F subform by school to reduce the searching I need to do. Then i enter participation data (date, event, etc.) in the Participation Data subform.

This seems to work ok, but we often have many folks at one event. Is there a way to select multiple records in the S&F subform and add the same data in the Participation Data form all at once? 
My initial thought was a way to make the S&F subform a combo box, select the records I want to edit, then add the participation data once, and have it save multiple records (one for each S&F record selected) in the participation data table. But I can't seem to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need at least one more table for participation. I would create this relationship as a one-to-many. One participation event to many students.

Teen if you created a form based on participation with your even data, you could have a subform to add participants from the S&F table.

Comment: Again, thanks for the help

I'm now running into trouble with the actual act of using a subform to add participants from the S&F table. 

I now have a separate table that records each event(eventlist) and another table (studparticipation) that just holds the event ID (PK) and student ID (PK from s&f table) in order to link the two.

What I can't figure out is how to use a form and the full S&F table (in a subform) to pull the student ID into the studentparticipation table along with the event ID.

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you build your form on a table or on a query? I also like to build them on queries. Then you may have to change the join so that it pulls all from one table, so that you can add.

Comment: I used a table, but I'm happy to change if it will make things easier. Can you explain how to do it with the query?

Comment: Build a basic select query through query builder, adding the tables that you need. I like to use the asterisk at the top to add all the fields, so that the forms source is dynamic if you change the table. Then change the join so the table that you will be using for your main form is funnelling into your subform table. Then use this as your source for the form.

Comment: To change the source form go to design view of the form and hit Alt+Enter. There is a little box in the top left corner where the rulers meet, make sure that you have clicked there to edit the record source. Then on the data tab of the property sheet you select your query from the drop-down list.